# Asterisk + Media Server Integration?

Tags: asterisk

How do i integrate Asterisk(VOIP - IP-PBX) to some media server or streaming server?

Asterisk + Darwin Streaming Server,Asterisk + Live555 media server,Asterisk + Ice Cast?
Asterisk + any other server
?
Please suggest some media servers and how to use that with Asterisk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asterisk 1.4 has support for Icecast http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Ices . 
Also an interesting module is jackaudio, you can hook input and output data to imaginable number of end-streams.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to pull audio from ice cast you can use a madplay with a bashscript like this.

in musiconhold.conf

```
[moh_from_icecase]
mode=custom
application=/etc/asterisk/my_moh.sh
```

in /etc/asterisk/my_moh.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
wget -q -T 120 -O - 'http://example.org:80/my_stream' | /usr/local/bin/madplay -Q -o raw:- --mono -R 8000 -a -10 -
```